# Importing node list with temporal info column

Tags: python, networkx, graph-theory

I feel like this is a stupid question but I have the stanford temporal email data set which is broken into source node, target node and timestamp in three columns.
I cannot for the life of me figure out how to import the nodes order by time.
I'm trying to use python and the networkx library but I can't seem to find any documentation on how to import a temporal info column as part of a graph node list.

My data is a simple csv with three col:

```
|source||target||ts|
|582||364||0|
|168||472||2797|
|168||912||3304|
|2||790||4523|
```

The rest of the csv is exactly the same for ~300000 lines

Comment: Hi there, could you please provide an example of your data?

Comment: this might be helpful ? https://snap.stanford.edu/snappy/index.html

Comment: What do you mean by "import the nodes order by time"? If you want the `ts` column as an edge attribute, you can read your csv into a pandas dataframe. Then use `g = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df=df, source = 'source', target = 'target', edge_attr = True)`. This will add the value in the `ts` column as an edge attribute named `ts`

Comment: @cookesd AHA! thanks for that, its obvious now that I see it! I was wrecking my mind trying to figure out how to force networkx to import the timestamp as a attribute for my edges. Classic tunnel visioning on the issue on my part. Thank you!